# calculate and replace special numbers in pages (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, numbers

I am trying to change format of special numbers in my pages.

Numbers format is similar this: **11,111.00 AUD**

And these changes should be applied on them:

1. **Extract** clean number from it: (11111)
2. **Calculate** cost of them: (11111 * 2)
3. **Change currency** String with USD
4. **Replace** Previous Result with Default Value: **22222 USD**

Please help me to complete this code:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('body').html( function(i,txt) {return txt.replace(/\d+,\d+.\d+ USD/,'blabla AUD'); });
});
```

Comment: why not do this on the server side, where i assume these numbers are coming from?

Comment: You'd need to escape the period in your RegEx (`\.`).

Comment: because I have not full access on it. like blogger and etc...

Comment: Can you help me in this Matt McDonald?

Comment: @user759595, you cannot manipulate another url's DOM

Comment: If it's possible, you should try filtering by class names or at least element types, rather than replacing the `.html` of the entire `$('body')`.

Comment: @Neal, Yes, I just do not have access to the currency module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `parseFloat('11,111.00 AUD'.replace(',',''))` method of javascript

**UPDATE**

```
return (parseFloat(txt.replace(/,/g,'')) * 2)+ " USD"
```

Comment: Can you complete your code for acts on all currency numbers in page?

Answer (score 1):

[**See demo of the following →**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWS7C/1/)

You will have to fix the formatter for this to work for return values above 999,999, but this should work pretty well for you:

```
var convertAUDtoUSD = function(i,txt) {
    var formatter = function( val ) {
            val = String(val);
            return (val.length > 3) ?
                        val.substring(0, val.length - 3) 
                        + "," 
                        + val.substring(val.length - 3, val.length)
                   : val;
        },
        replacer = function (str, p1, p2) {
            return formatter(parseInt(p1.replace(/\,/g,''),10) * 2) 
                   + p2.replace('AUD','USD');
        };

    return txt.replace(/(\d+,?\d+)(\.\d+\sAUD)/ig, replacer);
};

$('body').html( convertAUDtoUSD );
```

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/NWS7C/1/)

Comment: Thanks! it acted very Well. but have some Interaction in my main page. Is it possible for you to rewrite it without jquery?

Comment: Just change `$('body').html( convertAUDtoUSD );` to `document.body.innerHTML = convertAUDtoUSD( 0, document.body.innerHTML );` and it should work without jQuery.

Comment: How Can I fix the formatter for this to work for return values above 999,999?

Answer (score 0):

This will strip out the commas and 'AUD', multiply the resulting value by 2 and concatenate the 'USD' text.

return txt.replace(/(,|AUD)/g,'') * 2 + " USD";

Comment: I confirmed it works with "11,111.00 AUD".  What is the input which causes the NaN?